# PL/SQL block with %ROWCOUNT compiles but doesn't output result

Tags: oracle, plsql, rowcount

I am trying to print the first 3 records with the highest credit limit. My code compiles, but doesn't print anything despite having the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000` and I am a bit puzzled by that. The table shows up with no problem. Also, when I have only

```
EXIT WHEN high_credit%ROWCOUNT > 4;
```

the script goes into infinite loop.

The code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000

DECLARE
   CURSOR high_credit IS
   SELECT first_name, last_name, employee_id, credit_limit FROM employees
      ORDER BY credit_limit DESC;   
   emp_fname employees.first_name%TYPE;
   emp_lname employees.last_name%TYPE;
   emp_empno employees.employee_id%TYPE;
   emp_crd_lmt employees.credit_limit%TYPE;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First_Name ' || 'Last_Name ' || 'Employee_Id '
 || 'Credit_Limit');
   OPEN high_credit;
   LOOP
      FETCH high_credit INTO emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_empno, emp_crd_lmt;
      EXIT WHEN (high_credit%ROWCOUNT > 4) OR (high_credit%NOTFOUND);     
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_fname || ' ' || emp_lname || ' ' || emp_empno
 || ' ' || emp_crd_lmt);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE high_credit;
END;
```

[image: script output]

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    employee_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    credit_limit NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL,    
    CONSTRAINT employee_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)    
);

INSERT INTO employees VALUES (201, 'Susan', 'Brown', 30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (202, 'Jim', 'Kern', 25);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (203, 'Martha', 'Woods', 25);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (204, 'Ellen', 'Owens', 15);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (205, 'Henry', 'Perkins', 25);
```

[image: table employees]

The code works after the COMMIT; on the INSERT... as suggested:

[image: the code is working]

Comment: that's not how %rowcount is used.  %rowcount returns the number of rows that were modified with a DML.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, %rowcount does work for a select statement, here it will return the number of rows fetched last. You’ll either get 1 or 0. If it was a bulk collect then you could return a higher value. See the docs https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-0C789D68-82D8-4896-97BF-AF2356B9C8D5

Comment: It works after COMMIT; on the INSERT;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from invalid use of `SQL%ROWCOUNT` (as OldProgrammer said) (although, it doesn't affect your problem), it looks that you

- created the table and inserted rows in SQL Developer
- did **NOT** commit
- executed your PL/SQL script in SQL*Plus
- as inserts weren't committed, SQL*Plus session doesn't see those rows (but it sees the table as `CREATE TABLE` is a DDL)

Therefore

- `COMMIT` in SQL Developer
- then run your code in SQL*Plus

---

About the task you mentioned in the comment: see if this helps (I don't have your tables so I'm using Scott's `EMP`):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    cursor c1 is
  3      select * from emp
  4      order by sal desc;
  5    c1r c1%rowtype;
  6  begin
  7    open c1;
  8    loop
  9      fetch c1 into c1r;
 10      exit when c1%notfound or c1%rowcount > 3;
 11
 12      dbms_output.put_line(c1%rowcount ||': '|| c1r.ename ||': '|| c1r.sal);
 13    end loop;
 14    close c1;
 15  end;
 16  /
1: KING: 5001
2: FORD: 3000
3: SCOTT: 3000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: It's all SQL Developer, but, yes, I needed a COMMIT to get it working. This is where I got the idea of using the %ROWCOUNT as I did:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/a_samps.htm#563 (Sample2)

Comment: By the way, since I've got my code to work as I intended, do you mind sharing how would you write a code if you had to: "Create a PL/SQL block that fetches and displays the three employees with the highest credit limits. Order your output so that the employee with the highest credit limit is displayed first. Use %ROWTYPE and the explicit cursor attribute %ROWCOUNT."

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. In my example I also had to deal with the rows which contained NULL values (in your case sal column). Would the construct "exit when c1%notfound" be sufficient enough in those cases too? I am asking this because I also later added to my code in the Cursor declaration a logic structure WHERE sal IS NOT NULL (your example). It works in my code.

Comment: WHERE clause makes more sense, I'd say. EXIT clause will take care about exiting the loop once the cursor returns all rows it has. Without it, you'd end up in an infinite loop.